# Unity C# Vector 3 Mis-match

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm instantiating a Gameobject with a number of children at a certain offset. This Co-Routine is called once per child. I want to randomize the children's Y position and Lerp them back to their correct endPosition. However, for some reason my endPosition is getting affected by this change. The parts end up assembling at whatever the randomized Yoffset of the start position was.

**I'm only randomizing the startPos.y; why is my endPos being affected?**

A number of people have been stumped by this problem, so any help would be great.

```
IEnumerator TransitionAnim(Transform part, bool start)
    {
        float t = 0;

        if (start)
            {
        Vector3 startPos = new Vector3(part.position.x, Random.Range(30,-30), part.position.z);
        Vector3 endPos = new Vector3(part.position.x - startingOffset, part.position.y, part.position.z);

        while (t < duration)
            {
           t += Time.deltaTime;
           part.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, Mathf.SmoothStep(0,1F,t/duration));       
           yield return 0;   
            }
           part.position = endPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code runs just fine on my machine.  EndPos.y is not randomized.  Have you tried dropping a couple of debug.log's after you initialize startPos and endPos?

Answer (score 1):

I have wrote a small test using your code list above, the endPos is not changing, so the problem may lies in other functions. Here is my guess below:

1. your endPos is generated depends on the position of part(transform)
2. after some calculation, you assigned a value to part(transform)'s position, the position of part is changed
3. another game object trys to use the same transform part to generate its own endPos, but the position of part is changed already, so this game object will get a different endPos

if my guess is correct, there is the solution:

1. do not assign new value to part positon
2. try to use a new vector3 based on part's position